# Installing CouchDB on Android

Tags: android, couchdb, installation

I watch this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RdcKWYGqig)
and I followed a lot of tutorial how to install `couchDB` on my android phone but many of them need to install `CouchDB` application which should be on Play Store. e.g. like in the link above. But at this moment android `couchDB` application isn't on Play Store.

In [this tutorial](http://arandomurl.com/2011/02/13/developing-with-couchdb-on-android.html) I found that I looking for is needed to using couchdb on android:

Can you help me that where I can download this app? Will this app on android market in the future? I would like to install this app and use `couchDB` on my HTC desire. If you know the other way how to use `couchDB` on my device please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is my blog post, as mentioned in the header its out of date, I should update the link but the current installation instructions are at

http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-mobile-for-android/current

This is if you want to build an application that uses Couch for a backend

if you just want to play around with Couch on the device you can install the application that has a standalone version of couch along with a mobile admin interface

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.daleharvey.mobilefuton

Cheers

Dale